# Как установить icu and intl?

Tags: php, linux, apache2

Нужна помощь. Не могу установить пакеты для работы с фреймворком.

Пакеты `icu` и `intl`.

Выполняю: **sudo apt-get install php7.1-intl**

Не может найти пакет. Кто сталкивался подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для установки библиотеки `intl` с начало добавьте репозиторий в `ubuntu` а потом уже можно установить.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xsl
```

проверьте расширения php следующей командой

```
php -m
```

Или же просто сделайте так:

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

А для пакета `icu` выполните следующее:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install icu-devtools
```

Comment: а что это за пепозиторий  ppa:ondrej/php???

Comment: @dpi Это репозиторий для откуда можно скачать данный пакет.

Comment: @dpi вы читали на странице разработчика как устанавливать? http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

Comment: @Hellseher Ну и что там такого особого написано?

Comment: Да собственно что репы нету там. Вот и не совсемполная дока. Спасибо вопрос с вашей помощью решен. cakephp установлен.